# Which is the oldest written preserved version of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

There must be many old written versions of Mahabharata, probably as manuscripts or on leaves. I wanted to know that which is the oldest preserved written version of Mahabharata

Comment: This is not a dup of other. If the question remains closed, the answer is: "The oldest dated manuscript of our critical apparatus is a Nepali manuscript (Ñ3) which bears a date corresponding to A.D. 1511. The other dates are: A.D. 1519 (Ks), 1528 (Vi), 1598 (D2), 1620 (Da2), 1638 (K2), 1694 (K*), 1701 (Dr3), 1739 (Ko), 1740 (Bi), 1759 (B3), 1786 (B*), 1802 (D5), 1808 (Dn2), 1838 (Ms), and 1842 (Ms)." (from [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/Suk933__Sukthankar_ProlegomenaMBh1.txt)).